# How to optimize the query to update a table column with a column in another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have 2 tables. One table is cr_archive which has around 9000000 records. It has a column called v_sales_person which does not have values. I have another table called table_2 which has the same column called v_sales_person in which there are values. Both tables have columns called product_label,account_num. I want to select data from table _2 which has the same product_labels and account_num as in cr_archive and update the column v_sales_person in cr_archive with the values in table_2 which fulfill the above conditions(using oracle). I tried the following query.

```
update cr_archive a
set a.v_sales_person = (select distinct b.v_sales_person from table_2 b where a.account_num = b.account_num and A.PRODUCT_LABEL=b.PRODUCT_LABEL )
/
commit
/
```

But the query is taking more than 6 hours to process and don't know whether it gives the output. I have 2 questions.
1. Is the above query correct?
2. Is there any method to optimize the above query.

Comment: Can you post an execution plan and DDL? If you're updating 9.000.000 rows, indexing matters..
Also, "distinct" is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `select distinct` in the subquery.  It suggests that it could return more than one row.  Instead, use `rownum = 1`.  So, start with:

```
update cr_archive a
    set a.v_sales_person = (select b.v_sales_person
                            from table_2 b
                            where a.account_num = b.account_num and
                                  A.PRODUCT_LABEL = b.PRODUCT_LABEL and
                                  rownum = 1
                           );
```

You want to optimize this with an index on `table_2(account_num, PRODUCT_LABEL, v_sales_person)`.  The index is important for performance.

Next, this is updating all rows.  If that is not necessary, it is expensive.  So:

```
update cr_archive a
    set a.v_sales_person = (select b.v_sales_person
                            from table_2 b
                            where a.account_num = b.account_num and
                                  A.PRODUCT_LABEL = b.PRODUCT_LABEL and
                                  rownum = 1
                           )
    where a.v_sales_person is null or
          a.v_sales_person <> (select b.v_sales_person
                               from table_2 b
                               where a.account_num = b.account_num and
                                     A.PRODUCT_LABEL = b.PRODUCT_LABEL and
                                     rownum = 1
                              );
```

Finally, if you do need to update all rows, then it is going to be quite expensive.  You might find one of the following a viable alternative:

1. Reconstruct the table.  Massive inserts are faster than massive updates.
2. Forget it.  Just `JOIN` when you query the table to get the name.
3. Add a new table with the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO CR_ARCHIVE A 
USING (
          SELECT
              MAX(B.V_SALES_PERSON) AS V_SALES_PERSON,
              B.ACCOUNT_NUM,
              B.PRODUCT_LABEL
          FROM
              TABLE_2 B
          GROUP BY
              B.ACCOUNT_NUM,
              B.PRODUCT_LABEL
      )
B ON ( A.ACCOUNT_NUM = B.ACCOUNT_NUM
       AND A.PRODUCT_LABEL = B.PRODUCT_LABEL )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET A.V_SALES_PERSON = B.V_SALES_PERSON;
/
```

Cheers!!